# ssis 2008 The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters

Tags: ssis

I logged on as domain\user on a server (server A) and created a SSIS 2008 package, which loads some data from another server (server B) then exports to a text file on a network share (server C) (UNC: \\server C\path\text.txt).

It runs no problem in BIDS (server A). But failed in SQL Server agent job (also Server A). The job is configured under proxy account using credential: domain\user (the same one used to log in server A).

The error from the job:

Error: 2014-12-29 00:52:47.22
Code: 0xC001401E
Source: RPT_MiningOutput Connection manager "DataDump_DataMining_vw"
Description: The file name "\TORNADO\reporting$\Product MI Reporting\MyWorks\BI Cube\DataDump_DataMining_vw.txt" specified in the connection was not valid.
End Error

Error: 2014-12-29 00:52:48.30
Code: 0xC0202070
Source: RPT_MiningOutput Connection manager "DataDump_DataMining_vw"
Description: The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.

End Error

I can also navigate to that path under domain\user on server A. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a slash in your path name. I see `\TORNADO\reporting$` and would expect `\\TORNADO\reporting$` Not sure why it'd work via bids and not at the agent if that's the root cause, unless there are some missed configurations (check your warnings)

Comment: The missing slash is because the escape character in this forum, the path are for demo purpose so doesn't matter.

Comment: You say it doesn't matter but the number of times I've seen people tripped up by not having escaped properly in an SSIS Expression is non-zero. Besides, if the error reported is that `connection was not valid` *and* the visible data you provide about your problem shows an invalid path, you can see how one would quickly disregard the red herring of BIDS vs agent

Comment: Hi I meant the path is correct with double slash, it's only this way because stackoverflow use slash as escape character so shows one slash when I pasted the error message directly. The path is not an issue because I have verified and the package runs no problem in BIDS.